# I want the body of my site to move away from the sidenav when the animation opens

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I open my sidenav it just covers up a chunk of the body. I want the whole body to shift away from the sidenav when I open it so that the whole body is still able to see.

This is the whole site I'm making just for fun, but I have no idea where to start for making the sidenav push the body.

I have space to the right of the body for the body to push over as it is just a table, but I want the body to kind of stick to the sidenav as if it's position is decided completely by whether the sidenav is open or not.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #818181;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="20B.html">Next Page</a>
  <a href="20A.html">Previous Page</a>
  <a href="20A.html">First Page</a>
  <a href="20C.html">Last Page</a>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a runnable snippet, but it doesn't contain any of the non-nav content so we can't see what is happening to it. Please edit the code so it shows the problem.